# Change scheduled windows7 backup setting

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I have a Window7 backup task scheduled to run everyday to a shared drive that no longer exists
So I get an error message about it every day.

There seems to be no way to change/cancel an existing backup task. The 'change settings' option only lets you define a new one.

There is an option to stop the scheduled tasks but no way to remove it. Unfortunately backup uses it's own internal scheduler not the system task-schedule

Comment: Have you tried going to the backup and changing the settings from there?

Comment: @soandos - that's the point - how? There is a 'change settings' link but it just prompts you to create a new backup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete the job, and it does actually use the Windows Task Scheduler.

Here is the sample job I created. I checked the default time of 7 pm in Task Scheduler, then changed it to 5 pm to make sure I had the right one.

[image]

Then I went into `Administrative Tools>Task Scheduler>Task Scheduler Library>Microsoft>Windows>Windows Backup` where you can disable it or even delete it.

[image]

Deleting the job in Task Scheduler brings you back to the original screen in the Control Panel Backup panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you have to navigate to "task scheduler lib->windows->windows backup", it isn't listed in the "running tasks" and have to start the task scheduler as admin to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore. On the side there will be an option to turn off schedule.